# What is a "package" in terms of PHP Depend?

Tags: php, pdepend

On the http://pdepend.org/documentation/handbook/reports/overview-pyramid.html it is said that:

> NOP - The Number Of Packages metric counts the packages within the
>   analyzed software system.

How the "package" is determined? Is it just `@package` phpdoc attribute value?

Comment: I assume that the @package-Tag is meant. cf. this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194243/php-depend-and-package-annotations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a duplicate of [PHP Depend and @package-annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194243/php-depend-and-package-annotations)

Since community haven't voted for close and I don't want to have 1 not accepted questions - I answer myself.