# JAX-B annotations for elements that inherit from a parent

Tags: java, jaxb

When adding `JAX-B` Java annotations for Java classes - if I have a parent **Class Entry**, with two children, **Book** and **JournalArticle**,

Would I add these annotations for all three classes:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement
```

ie:

```
@XmlSeeAlso({au.com.library.Book.class, au.com.library.JournalArticle.class})
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement
public abstract class Entry implements Serializable{


private static final long serialVersionUID = -1895155325179947581L;

@XmlElement(name="title")
protected String title;
@XmlElement(name="author")
protected String author;
@XmlElement(name="year")
protected int year;
```

and

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement
public class Book extends Entry {

@XmlElement(name="edition")
private String edition;
@XmlElement(name="publisher")
private String publisher;
@XmlElement(name="placeOfPublication")
private String placeOfPub;
```

and

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement
public class JournalArticle extends Entry {

@XmlElement(name="journalTitle")
private String journalTitle;
@XmlElement(name="volume")
private String volume;
@XmlElement(name="issue")
private String issue;
@XmlElement(name="pageNumbers")
private String pgNumbers;
```

Comment: You should add the annotations only if those classes will be marshaled/unmarshaled by the JAX-B process. Remember that is not the same sending/retrieving a parent class or a child class by the WS. They will be treated as different classes.

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza - I want them to both be treated as type "Entry". I am making a list of these Entry objects, and when I add to the list, I first check if the object exists, and only add if the object doesnt already exist in the list (using the List().contains() method) - but it keeps re-adding the same items - and when I debug, when it checks if the object already exists (when I add the SAME Book() object which is already in the list with the same attributes) it gives the new Book a different ID number to the existing Book object(that has the exact same attributes).

Comment: Note that the classes marshaled/unmarshaled by JAX-B must not have any business logic method (i.e. `equals` method). When the list is unmarshaled (in the consumer or the provider side), you will get a totally new element (different from the one you sent). For your case, I would use a custom `Comparator<Entry>` in the method instead of the `List#contains`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The annotation [`XmlAccessorType`](http://jaxb.java.net/jaxb20-pr/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlAccessorType.html) can be inherited so I believe it is not mandatory to declare it again on child classes.

```
@Inherited
@Retention(value=RUNTIME)
@Target(value={PACKAGE,TYPE})
public @interface XmlAccessorType
```

This is not the case for [`XmlRootElement`](http://jaxb.java.net/jaxb20-pr/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlRootElement.html), so you will have to annotate each base class with it.

You can find more information on the [`@Inherited`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Inherited.html) annotation on the javadoc.

**Update for your comment:**

`@Retention(value=RUNTIME)` means that the class keeps this annotation even at runtime, that is, a program can use the Java reflection API to check if the annotation is present on a class.

`@Target(value={PACKAGE,TYPE})` means that this annotation can be used to annotate classes, interfaces or enums (this is for the `value=TYPE`), and also at a whole package level (this is for `value=PACKAGE`). You can see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099431/whats-the-point-of-package-annotations) explaining how this can be useful.

More information on the Javadoc:

- [`@Retention`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Retention.html)
- [`RetentionPolicy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/RetentionPolicy.html)
- [`@Target`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Target.html)
- [`ElementType`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/ElementType.html)

Comment: Thanks for the response - so in this case, what would the @Retention(value=?), and the @Target(value=?) equal?