# How annotation check validation at runtime

Tags: java, reflection, annotations

I am working with custom annotation building ,I am creating some custom annotation that will validating some data.I am not able to write the annotation processor for that annotation.

i.e. **I created a custom annotation UserRole as :**

```
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ ElementType.PARAMETER })
public @interface UserRole
{
    int[] value() default {0};
}
```

I will use this annotation as follow :

```
import java.util.List;
public class Demo
{
    public void checkValidUser(@UserRole({1,2})List<Integer> roles){
        // some code here
        }
}
```

I want to write Annotation processor so that I can check if given list contain any role that is specified in annotation at runtime because I will provide List at runtime.
I need help to write that annotation processor.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After your last comment  lets try to understand how does  how does jpa works

when you use  **dao.find(id, class);** the entity manager  checks class metadata like( primary key and tablename...   etc) which is parsed before ..   (as i was trying tell  you in  the classInfo example)  and adds it to   entitymanager has map field

```
Map<Class,EntityInfo>
```

named as entities  ( for my example it must be map must be like that  Map ) when you run  dao.find(id,User.class) .. it checks that map. gets the id field  and table information  and parsers from there ( parses sql something like this     "select * from" + entity.getTableName() +" where "+ entity.getIdField().getName() +" = "+ id ) and runs query and returns the result ...  i hope now you can understand what i was trying to tell you  ..

[How and where are Annotations used in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1372876/how-and-where-are-annotations-used-in-java) ... good answer first read what is annotation ..

Annotation describe way what the method , field or class  will do  .. so it is not passing parameter, it  is defining a rule ... for your example if there is 3 type of user  .. Admin Normal Guest     and u have a method which can be call by only user types Admin .. like deleteProduct..

u have to use :

```
@UserRoles([Admin])
public void deleteProduct(){
///......
} 

@UserRoles([Admin,Normal])
public void commentProduct() {}
```

for example you have an url  with 
  **www.site.com/comments/15/likes?offset=15**

and  you are writing an webroute handler ..  which has annotations   **@WebMethod** (Post , Get , Put, Delete etc)   , **@WebParameter** (POST and GET PARAMETER  , **@URLParam**( URL PARAM handler) ;

comment/:id/likes/

you have to do that like that ..

```
public class Comments {
 // handles url path like  /comments/12/likes?offset=15 
 @WebMethod(MethodType.GET)
  @WebURL("comment/:id/likes/") 
  public void listLikes(@WebParameter(name="offset") int offset, @URLParam("id") long id) {
  //operatio to Do  so here offset will be 15  ,id 12
}
}
```

the logic of annotations something like that .. 
Here is an another example ..

First you have to create a holder Object  ( which holds all information readed by reflection )  so you can avolute it with proxy of object ..

For example if you have  annotation like @Id and @ColumnName for Fields ,  and  @Async for method ...

you have to write to Class Object  FieldInfo which has field Id ,name

For **Class**

```
 class ClassInfo {
   private  final      Set<MethodInfo> methods; 
   private final Set<FieldInfo> fields; 
}
```

For **Fields** :

```
 class FieldInfo {
    private   boolean id=false; 
    private Field fieldInfo ; 
    private  String columnName;
    /// More info for fields like field name  
    // constructors 
    //Getters and Setters 
         //methods to use 
}
```

For **Methods** :

```
 class MethodInfo {
       private Method methodInfo; 
       private  boolean async= false;  
        /// More info for methods  like field name  
            // constructors 
            //Getters and Setters 
         //methods to use 
    }
```

So u can use reflection  ( i do it only for Field  you can do it for method and method parameters as like as you want  )

```
  final   ClassInfo classInfo = new ClassInfo(); 
  Field[] fields =   Demo.class.getFields(); 
 for(final field :fields) {
    FieldInfo fieldInfo = new FieldInfo(field);
    if(field.hasAnnotation(Id.class)) {
      fieldInfo.setId(true); 
   } 
    if(field.hasAnnotation(ColumnName.class){
     final ColumnName col = field.getAnnotation(ColumnName.class); 
     fieldInfo.setColumnName(col.value());
    }
 }
```

and methods , method parameters you have parse what u have to do with it ..

i hope this information helps you ... 
if you have any more question  , feel free to ask

Comment: Am i able to get class object here because what i know is that annotation processing is done before compilation phase .So I think Demo.class will not work here

Comment: I know it is logical thats why i asked

Comment: @UserRole({1,2})List<Integer> roles   containing parameters 1,2 right ? ..  so  u can   check it in your method .. because of not logical .. writing a private method and checking   1,2 is  in roles  anywhere you want ..

Comment: but if you think it is logical check another way   proxyhandler

Comment: For logical what I mean is that how other annotation like @Length,@Max in hibernate,@RoleAllowed(in jersey) work