# Syntax error on token "myBag", VariableDeclaratorId expected after this token AND myBag cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, generics

I am getting a variabledeclaratorID expected after this token error for my instantiation of myBag in the ShoppingCart constructor. I can't figure out why.

[image]

Tried following the IDE fix suggestions, tried googling for similar errors.

Comment: Misplaced annotation `@SuppressWarnings`: Annotations are meta-meta-objects which can be used to describe other meta-objects. Meta-objects are classes, fields and methods.   ( see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1372876/how-and-where-are-annotations-used-in-java ) . Place annotation above constructor assuming that was your intention.

Comment: This was it - thank you! I didn't realize that annotations can only describe meta objects.

Comment: Please don't post images of code, errors, logs, or other text; see [ask]

Answer (score 0):

User 5f3bde39-70a2-4df1-afa2-47f61b comment to my post pointing out my error in the annotation placement was the issue.